# Can a remote conditional have "might" in the protasis?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals, conditional-perfect, protasis

In the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston and Pullum, the authors write:

> A remote conditional must have a modal auxiliary as the apodosis verb
>   (usually *would, should, could*, or *might*) and a modal preterite or irrealis *were* in the protasis.
>   (p.739)

A remote conditional is a conditional sentence using past or past perfect subjunctive mood.

I'm wondering if "might" can be used in the protasis of a remote conditional.
I could find examples of remote conditionals whose protases use "would, should, or could",
but could not find an example using "might" in the protasis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can. Consider:

> - If he might have escaped a fine, he would have accepted the caution
> - If there might have been snow, they would have agreed to go to the mountains.
> - It would have been worth the effort, if it might have had any effect.
> - If the hephalumps might have reason to do so, they'd eat all the unicorn's artichokes.

Comment: @ivanhoescott All of those examples have the form of ***"might" + bare infinitival.*** None of them have a *present perfect* in them.

Comment: @F.E. Are you saying that "have" in the main clause is bare infinitive in all those examples?

Comment: @ivanhoescott In all of them, yes. (According to the 2002 *CGEL*. See page 107: _The central modal auxiliaries take bare infinitival complements -- and no other kind of complement._) The head verb "might" carries the primary tense (present tense vs past tense). In these types of constructions, the verb "have" is a plain form, and so, has no primary tense (notice that there can be no "might had" versions).

Comment: @F.E. In all of the examples except the last one, is "have" in the main clause not an auxiliary verb?

Comment: @F.E. I'm asking. Is it an auxiliary verb?
I've never heard that an auxiliary verb can be bare infinitive.

Comment: @F.E. Don't you find it strange?

Comment: @ivanhoescott Remember that in a sequence of verbs like this, that only one of them can carry a primary tense, and that one is the first verb in that sequence (for a canonical clause).

Comment: @F.E. "Find what strange?" I've never heard that an auxiliary verb can be bare infinitive.

Comment: @ivanhoescott There's page 104-6, "2.3 Combinations of auxiliary verbs", which might help you out. (Note that *infinitival* is a type of construction, which is headed by a *plain form* of a verb.) -- Note [44.i] which has "modal, plain form" and examples.

Comment: @ivanhoescott The English auxiliaries are surprisingly regular in their complementation, so modals are always followed by infinitives, perfective *HAVE* is followed by a past participle, continuous *BE* by a present participle and passive *BE* by a past participle.  If more than one of them appear in a clause they always appear in that order. ***They might have been being tutored by eggheads***: have = infinitive; been = past participle; being = present participle; tutored = past participle. So non-modal auxiliaries can take many different forms :)

Comment: @F.E. Maybe I should have said that all those examples have "might have" + past participle.

Comment: @F.E. You must know what I'm talking about.
There's a big difference between "might have" + past participle and "might" + bare infinitive.

Comment: @F.E. OK, please explain why you think there's no difference between "might have" + past participle and "might" + bare infinitive.

Comment: @ivanhoescott I've already explained it, and have also provided related page numbers in the 2002 *CGEL* (which I assume you have a copy of, considering what was said in the original post). The author of this answer-post, "Araucaria", is a professional teacher of English grammar, and he will probably enjoy discussing this topic some more with you (though, remember that there is a difference in time zones).

Comment: @Araucaria "They might have been being tutored by eggheads: have = infinitive;"
Is "have" not an auxiliary verb?

Comment: @F.E. "I've already explained it"
Are you saying that the two sentences "he might have escaped a fine" and "he might escape a fine"
have the same grammatical structure?

Comment: @ivanhoescott I hope you've noticed that there's been an addition to the original post (I've added a so-called 2nd conditional in there for you!). Yes, the non-modal auxiliary verbs *BE, HAVE* and  dummy *DO* have tenses, (and therefore present simple, third person singular and past simple forms) as well as participle and infinitive forms, just like lexical verbs.

Comment: @ivanhoescott Is my hephalump example not enough for your present enquiry?

Comment: @ivanhoescott Don't put words into my mouth. You have a copy of *CGEL* (I assume). I provided some page numbers of some related info that is in *CGEL*. I even provided an excerpt in my 2nd comment here in this thread which you probably ought to re-read. If you have a grammatical question, then consider posting a question thread (like you did for this one); and/or direct your questions at "Araucaria".

Comment: Hmm, there's also *I would treat you with respect. I wouldn't your friends* which is why I backed off the comparative thing. I'll have a read and a muse. Incidentally, talking about suplementaries, here's why I wrote about *restrictive relative clauses* the other week, when I was having a brain episode having read too much Word Grammar [that's when I put something about some relative word being the head of a clause or seomething ... uurgh] [RCs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195896/what-is-the-usage-of-in-it-fat-in-this-sentence/195938#195938) It's the bit at the bottom ...